# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter, JS calling WS

Tags: javascript, json

This is part of my js file that contains the WS call:

```
            var ListaObjetoProductosMasivos = { listaObjetos: []};

       var listaObjetos = [];
        for (c = 0; c < nombreProductos.length; c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < idCentros.length; d++) {
                var ObjetoProductosMasivos = { nombreProducto: nombreProductos[c], idProducto: idProductos[c], idCentro: idCentros[d] }
                listaObjetos.push(ObjetoProductosMasivos);
            }
        }

        ListaObjetoProductosMasivos["listaObjetos"] = listaObjetos;

        var jsonValue = JSON.stringify({ ListaObjetoProductosMasivos: ListaObjetoProductosMasivos });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://172.24.1.117:5561/Service1.asmx/traeStockMasivo",
            data: jsonValue,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response){},error: function (msg) {}});
```

The WS receives the class ListaObjetoProductosMasivos, which contains a list of ObjetoProductosMasivos:

```
    public class ObjetoProductosMasivos
{
    public string nombreProducto = "";
    public string idProducto = "";
    public string idCentro = "";
}

public class ListaObjetoProductosMasivos
{
    public List<ObjetoProductosMasivos> listaObjetos = new List<ObjetoProductosMasivos>();
}
```

I have tried everything, is there something I´m missing?

Edit:

This is what is in the var jsonValue, just before the WS call: "{\"ListaObjetoProductosMasivos\":{\"listaObjetos\":[{\"nombreProducto\":\"123\",\"idProducto\":\"123\",\"idCentro\":\"3005\"}]}}"

Comment: `listaObjetos.push();` doesn't do anything. `x` doesn't seem to be used anywhere either.

Comment: @Kei000 are you getting any errors? Do a `console.log(msg);` in the js error handler.

Comment: Yes, I get this error: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter.